# How to make filter work when data is being obtained from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-alertdialog

The below code is used to open an AlertDialog which enables one to search for data base on the items in the alert dialog

```
public void FilterIcon(){


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    selecedItem = new ArrayList<>();
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setCustomTitle(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout,null))

            .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.Category,-1,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    switch (i){

                        case  0:
                            Selection = 0;
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"BOOKS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            Selection =1;
                            selecedItem.add("PC GAMES");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"PC  GAMES",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            Selection = 2;
                            selecedItem.add("PS3 GAMES");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"PS3 GAMES",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            Selection =3;
                            selecedItem.add("PS4 GAMES");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"PS4 GAMES",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }

                }



            });
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            selecedItem.clear();




        }
    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });







    AlertDialog dialog =  builder.create();

    dialog.show();
}


public int getSelection() {
    return Selection;
}
```

I created the getSelection()method in order to know what the user has selected and pass that value to another activity.So if the user pressed the item which is at index 0 then Selection is set to 0.The other activity is the one responsible for doing the search.The code for the other activity is:

```
package com.example.database.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.database.R;
import com.example.database.models.Post;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecentPostsFragment extends PostListFragment {

private RecyclerView mRecycler;
private DatabaseReference myDatabase;

public int selection;



public RecentPostsFragment(){


}



@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.messages_list);

}

@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

    Log.d("TAG", "getQuery: Selection"+ getSelection());

    if(getSelection()==0){

        return databaseReference.child("Book");



    }else if(getSelection()==1) {

        return databaseReference.child("PC GAMES");
    }
    else if(getSelection()==2){

        return  databaseReference.child("PS3 GAMES");
    }

    else {

        return databaseReference.child("PS4 GAMES");
    }


}


@Override
public void setLayout() {
    super.setLayout();
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager mManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1);
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);
}
```

}

The problem that im facing is that selection is always zero...I can seem to make the value returned by getSelection() to be another value.It always returns a zero.But after a while when the activity has been created again it calls the correct value how can i make it the filter instant